# XCode builds app to iPad but debugging is not allowed

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, debugging

when I run my app on iPad it builds my app and then I got error:

```
     "Could not launch 'AppName', timed out waiting for app to launch".
```

Though, after this error, app is working perfectly on device. I think that it's caused by some sort of setting "Debug is not allowed" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem - Deleting derived data didn't work. In my case I found out that I was building the debug with an Ad Hoc provisioning profile.

Comment: I fixed the problem, with the same solution)

Answer (score 1):

Also you might try to **Reset Content and Settings** within your iOS Simulator or to open the XCode Organzier, navigate to your project and **delete** all **Derived Data**. Sometimes these actions help by your given problem.

Comment: understood about Derived Data, but could u plz explain how to Reset Content and Settings?

Comment: Of course! Open the simulator and within the main menu at "iOS Simulator" there is another submenu point named "Reset Content and Settings".

Comment: Are you using CoreData within your project and do you create a NSMangedObjectContext when launching the app?

Comment: I use CoreData, I didn't create a NSMangedObjectContext

Comment: I am having the same problem. Deleting derived data didn't work. I am creating NSManagedObjectContext.